# Issue with Django and React Full Stack Project Deployment: Page Not Found Error

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework, deployment, react-redux, react-router

I'm working on a full-stack project where I've set up email functionality for a password reset, including a link in the email. During development, the link is in the format:

```
"http://localhost:5173/api/user/reset/MjM/bzhdv5-a592eeb0c716dc2ac5a3771a670cbcaa"
```

Here is the relevant routing code in my React application:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
      <Route index element={<Home />} />
      <Route
        path="sendpasswordresetemail"
        element={<SendPasswordResetEmail />}
      />
      <Route
        path="api/user/reset/:id/:token"
        element={<ResetPassword />}
      />
    </Route>
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

When a user clicks on the link during development, it correctly takes them to the Reset Password page, and they can reset their password.

However, after deploying the site with the Django backend hosted on PythonAnywhere, the backend sends the email with a link in this format:

```
https://myAppName.netlify.app/api/user/reset/MjM/bzgxdl-47b662f540b19c5d719d4b609d52f751
```

When clicking this link, it shows a "Page Not Found" error:

> Page Not Found
> Looks like you've followed a broken link or entered a URL that doesn't exist on this site.

I've noticed that manually entering any route, such as `/login`, `/register`, or others, also results in the same problem.

Could someone help me identify the issue? Manually entering the URL doesn't work. Any assistance or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It seems that whenever i'm writing the url manually it doesn't work. i've tried to go to /login, /register and other routes too. all routes shows this problem when i'm writing the route manually